# Replacing = with in using sed

Tags: sed

I have a string like below

```
abc="where session = '001122' and indicator = 'X'"
```

I want to convert it to

```
eng="where session in ('001122') and indicator in ('X')"
```

I have tried like below using `sed` in bash

```
eng=$(echo $abc | sed -r "s/=\s+('[^']+')/in (\1)/g")
```

I am still get the input itself. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: `$abc` is probably empty: It's the variable named abc, not the string `abc`.

Comment: `eng=...` assigns an environment variable, not replaces part of a string.

Comment: The capture group `(...)` needs to be escaped as `\(...\)` or you need to use a -E flag or similar.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please check now I corrected the Question. But still getting the same result

Comment: Your proposed solution works with gnu sed.  Perhaps you are using a different sed?  (But in that case, I would expect you to get errors about `-r`, so this is a shot in the dark.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unadorned `sed` with escaped to escape the capture group parentheses (`\(` and `\)`), as well as one-or-more quantifiers (`\+`):

```
$ eng=$(echo "$abc" | sed "s/=\s\+'\([^']\+\)'/in ('\1')/g"
$ echo "$eng"
where session in ('001122') and indicator in ('X')
```

It is also probably a good idea to quote your expansion of `abc`, since it has spaces in it, but not strictly necessary in this context.

Your original code may not have worked because `-r` is a GNU extension. The synonym `-E` used to be as well, but is now part of the POSIX standard, and should therefore be relatively portable. The following version should therefore have no problems either:

```
$ eng=$(echo "$abc" | sed -E "s/=\s+'([^']+)'/in ('\1')/g"
```